# fetch markers from database and display on google map

Tags: javascript, sql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map that works fine for static values, displays different places with different color markers. However i wish to make this dynamic and fetch the position of markers from database

Database structure would be something like this

```
id   latitude     longitude     status
1   -33.890542    151.274856      1
2   -33.923036    151.259052      1
3   -34.028249    151.157507      2
4   -33.80010     151.28747       1
5   -33.950198    151.259302      2
```

i wish that the positions having status 1 should be of one color and the position having status 2 should be of another color.

At present the code that i have is

```
var locations = [
  ['<h4>Bondi Beach</h4>', -33.890542, 151.274856],
  ['<h4>Coogee Beach</h4>', -33.923036, 151.259052],
  ['<h4>Cronulla Beach</h4>', -34.028249, 151.157507],
  ['<h4>Manly Beach</h4>', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
  ['<h4>Maroubra Beach</h4>', -33.950198, 151.259302]
];

// Setup the different icons and shadows
var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';

var icons = [
  iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',      
  iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
]
var iconsLength = icons.length;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  panControl: false,
  zoomControlOptions: {
     position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
  }
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  maxWidth: 160
});

var markers = new Array();

var iconCounter = 0;

// Add the markers and infowindows to the map
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: icons[iconCounter]
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

  iconCounter++;
  // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
  if(iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
    iconCounter = 0;
  }
}

function autoCenter() {
  //  Create a new viewpoint bound
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  //  Go through each...
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
            bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
  }
  //  Fit these bounds to the map
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
autoCenter();
```

Can anyone please tell me how can i fetch the marker's position according to the status from database and also alot them different colors depending on latitude and longitude's status

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Don't you know how to fill the `locations`-variable with the values from the DB, or don't you know how to create a marker based on the `status`?

Comment: So you need something server-side to extract data from a database (what kind?) and output it client-side, either directly into your javascript or via an ajax response. Suggest you go away and think about databases and server-side code.  See also https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 for example

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps is a client-side API. Your markers are stored in a server side database

Don't confuse things.

Using standard server side techniques, output a JavaScript variable with your locations variable:

```
<?php
$locationsString = '[';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($locations); $i++) {
  if ($i > 0) {
    $locationsString .= ', ';
  }
  $locationsString .= '[' . $locations['title'] . ', ' .
      $locations['lat'] . ', ' . $locations['lng'] . ']'; 
}
echo '<script>var locations="' . $locationsString . '";</script>';
?>
```

There are almost countless variations on this basic idea. For instance, you could [retrieve the variable data via an AJAX call](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3).